# Unable to change submit callback for commerce_add_to_cart form

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm building the commerce add to cart form programmatically, and I'm trying to use my own submit handler.

However, no matter what I try, I'm not able to do so. It's really weird - I can override the one that is generated by the commerce itself, but not this one.

Stripped code is below. Note: to test it, create one product and replace product ID in the constant defined at start.

`temp.info` file:

```
name = Temporary
description = Temporary module for testing.
package = Custom
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.0
dependencies[] = commerce_cart
dependencies[] = commerce_product
dependencies[] = commerce_line_item
```

`temp.module` file:

```
define('TEMP_CUSTOM_PRODUCT_ID', 1);

function temp_menu() {
  $items['temp'] = array(
    'title' => 'Temporary page',
    'page callback' => 'temp_page',
    'page arguments' => array(),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function temp_page() {
  // Create a sample product and use its ID here.
  $product_ids = array(TEMP_CUSTOM_PRODUCT_ID);
  $product = commerce_product_load(TEMP_CUSTOM_PRODUCT_ID);
  // Build the line item we'll pass to the Add to Cart form.
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, 0, array(), 'product');
  $line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = $product_ids;
  $line_item->data['context']['add_to_cart_combine'] = TRUE;
  // Generate a form ID for this add to cart form.
  $form_id = commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id($product_ids);
  // Add the display path to the line item's context data array if specified.
  $line_item->data['context']['display_path'] = current_path();
  // Build the Add to Cart form using the prepared values.
  $form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item, TRUE, array());

  return drupal_render($form);
}

function temp_submit() {
  drupal_set_message('Custom submit handler is being called.');
}

function temp_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Dirty, but this check works for testing.
  if (arg(0) == 'temp') {
    $form['submit']['#submit'] = array('temp_submit');
    $form['#submit'] = array('temp_submit');
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

Every time you submit the form, it will trigger default submit handler.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong - I'm a goober. We switched from using button level handlers to form level handlers to ensure enter key presses didn't submit a form illegitimately or something. In any event, you should be using hook_form_alter(), not drupal_get_form() and then monkeying with the $form array. That's likely your real issue here.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Ryan. However, this still doesn't work - I can successfully change submit callback when Commerce generates the form, but not when I do so from a custom module. I updated the sample code in my question. Do you have any other ideas?